# Merge extra contents to the left when splitting one column to two with multiple delimiters

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data.frame column I want to split into two columns, as delimited by a space character.  If there are multiple delimiters, I still only want two columns, merging the extra contents to the first result column.  So this:

```
dat <- data.frame(full_name = c("first1 last1", "first2 middle2 last2"))

             full_name
1         first1 last1
2 first2 middle2 last2
```

Should become:

```
      first_name last_name
1         first1     last1
2 first2 middle2     last2
```

I'm using `separate()` from the tidyr package, which handles extra delimiters by merging to the right like this:

```
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
  separate(full_name, c("first_name", "last_name"), " ", extra = "merge")

  first_name     last_name
1     first1         last1
2     first2 middle2 last2
```

Can what I want be done with a tidyr function, and if not, how else can I split a column only on the final delimiter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dat %>% 
 separate(full_name, c("first_name", "last_name"), " (?=[^ ]+$)", extra = "merge")

      first_name last_name
1         first1     last1
2 first2 middle2     last2
```

Comment: It leaves a trailing space in the first column words. I added a space in the search and it took it out `sep=" (?=[^ ]+$)"`. And if you add the space you won't need `merge=`.

Comment: @PierreLafortune - didn't leave spaces in my test. Thanks though

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. I don't need the `extra = "merge"` argument anymore either. Could you explain how that regex works here?

Comment: Non-greedy (or opposite, greedy? always confuse them) backward lookup looks for end of line and goes all the way until it finds a space. Then split by this space

Comment: Doesn't work for more than 2 columns. In this case I need to apply `separate` multiple times. Any solution?